# Alignment in nav menu

Tags: css, html, position, nav

I'm working on a nav bar and dropdown menu using only CSS.

I'm trying to align the sub menu with respect to the parent element `.dropdown`. When I use `position:relative` on any parent container, so that I can add `position:absolute` the child elements, very strange formatting things start to happen.

---

```css
/* Nav */

header nav {
 float: right;
 margin-top: 43px;
     border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 
 }
 

 
 header nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 50px;
  
  }
  
     header nav li a {
  color: black;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-duration: .2s;
     }
       
     header nav li a:hover {
  color: orange;
       }
  
/* DROPDOWN MENU */


.dropdown {
 
}
.drop-nav {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    border-style: none;
    border-color:black;
    padding:10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    left:40%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: grey;
    color:white;
}
.drop-nav li{
    margin-left:20px;
}

.dropdown:hover .drop-nav {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <h1>
                <img src="logo.jpg" alt="coffeeology" />
            </h1>
            <nav>
                <ul class="main-nav">
                        <li><a href="#" title="home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="about us">About Us</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" title="menu">Menu</a>
                            <ul class="drop-nav">
                                <li>Beverages</li>
                                <li>Breakfast Items</li>
                                <li>Brunch</li>
                                <li>Gelato</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="daily specials">Daily Specials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="contact us">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

The end objective here is to keep the sub menu in a relevant position across various window sizes. Aligning the sub menu to a larger element doesn't solve the problem because the sub menu won't stay fixed with respect to the `.dropdown`class.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Post an image with what you want it to look like. If you don't have enough rep you can post it as a link or in the comments.

Comment: I agree with @sdcr, I'm finding it difficult to understand exactly what the issue is. Is this the sort of thing you are after? https://jsfiddle.net/dnmau1gc/

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you're looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/28qmkLsf/

```
/* DROPDOWN MENU */


.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}
.drop-nav {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    border-style: none;
    border-color:black;
    padding:10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    left:0%;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    color:white;
    width: 150px;
}
.drop-nav li{
    margin-left:20px;
    display: block;
}
```